# Free 2d array. Static pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, access-violation

I have a static pointer

```
   static int **2dArr;
```

and then I allocate memory for 2d array. 
How can I free that memory and replace it with another array?

```
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void func(int **arr) {
    int i,j,k,tmp;
    int **destMatrix = NULL;
destMatrix = (int**) malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

if ((destMatrix == NULL)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    destMatrix[i] = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (destMatrix[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}



for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);
arr = NULL;
arr = destMatrix;

}
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int main() {
   2dArr = (int**) malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
   if (2dArr== NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
     }


for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    2dArr[i] = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (2dArr[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            exit(2);
    }
}
    func(2dArr);
    // try to print new array, access violation
 }
```

I free memory and try to replace the pointer. But then I have a access violation. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Loop through and free each pointer in the second dimension, then free the main pointer

Comment: "I free memory and try to replace the pointer" — you free the memory but you *do not* replace the pointer. You only replace its copy (the `arr` variable in `func`). The original pointer (whatever it is really called, it cannot be `2dArr`, this is not a real identifier) remains unchanged and points to now-freed memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things:

- You need to pass the argument by reference in func:
  `void func(int ***arr) {`
- Then change the way you free things:
  `free((*arr)[i]);`
  and 
  `free(*arr);`
- and finally change how you reassign arr:
  `*arr = destMatrix;`
- also, don't name variables starting with a number -- it doesn't work.
- (also, you had `++i` instead of `i++` at the for loop at the end of func ) this doesn't actually matter -- see the comment below

I debugged these issues using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.intro), check it out.

Working code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void func(int ***arr) {
  int **destMatrix = NULL;
  destMatrix = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

  if ((destMatrix == NULL)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    destMatrix[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (destMatrix[i] == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
      exit(2);
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    free((*arr)[i]);
  }
  free(*arr);
  *arr = destMatrix;

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {
  int **tdArr = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
  if (tdArr== NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    tdArr[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (tdArr[i] == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
      exit(2);
    }
  }

  func(&tdArr);
  // try to print new array, does not get access violation

  //assign numbers 0-99
  int j;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
      tdArr[i][j] = i*10+j;
    }
  }
  //print numbers
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
      printf("%d\n", tdArr[i][j]);
    }
  }

  //free internal arrays
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    free(tdArr[i]);
  }
  //free outer array
  free(tdArr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the last observation matter?

Comment: @another.anon.coward
if you `++i` instead of `i++` in:

`for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {`  
`free((*arr)[i]);`  
`}`  
Then you neglect to free index 0.

(how do I add newlines to comments?)

Comment: Nope. You do free all of them. [See this](http://www.ideone.com/GaEif). The way `for` works in that after initialization & condition check, the body is executed before the value change is made. See [this](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx) for more clarification

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but keep in mind that the statement

```
arr = destMatrix;
```

in `func` only sets the local copy of your pointer to `destMatrix`.  Back in `main` (and globally), `2dArr` (or whatever you actually called it, since as @n.m. noted this isn't a valid identifier) still has its original `malloc`ed value even though you've successfully freed all of the pointers in `func`.  If you try to use or free that pointer (or the old pointers it still [likely] points to) elsewhere then you could get various errors.  (In this case, be happy you're getting errors -- you could instead be silently destroying memory that some other process is depending on.)  If you intend to change `2dArr` in `func`, you need to declare

```
void func(int ***arr);
```

and call it with

```
func(&2dArr);
```

so that you can access and change the original values via dereferencing, e.g.

```
free((*arr)[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `func` you free the memory for the static var `2darr` and it looks like you intend to set it to `destMatrix` but you are only setting a copy of the input pointer variable to `func`.

If you change to `void func(int **& arr)`, then you can set `2darr`, this is passing the int** by reference instead of value.